# How to print a string in backward, in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I know if I write my scheme code in the following way and type in (word  ‘(a b c)), it will out put  the list in the same order. Could you please tell me if there was a way I can print it out in opposite order. Ex- (list ‘c ‘b ‘a). 
it needs to be the user's input I print out in opposite order. So, I can't call it (reverse '(a b c)). since the user input can be something like '(x y z).
Thanks a lot.

> (define(word x )
>
> > (if(null? x) x
> >
> > > (cons(car x)(word (cdr x)))))

---

> (word '(a b c))
>
> (list 'a 'b 'c)

Answer (score 6):

```
(reverse '(a b c))
```

will reverse your string.  However I suspect that this is probably homework and you are supposed to write your own `reverse` function.

If so, can you reverse an empty list?  If you have a list and have the reverse of the rest of the list, can you get the reverse of the whole list?  Can you see how to make a function that reverses the list from these pieces?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
 (list->string (reverse (string->list "market")))
 "tekram"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: `cons` creates a list composed of its first argument followed by its second argument. Right now, you're using it to create a list of the first element followed by the same function applied to the rest of the elements, and that creates a list in the same order as it was.

What do you suppose would happen if you created a list of the same function applied to the rest of the elements followed by the first element?

Comment: `cons` does not create a list but a cons cell.  Other than that, good hint.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your information and help. I found a way to do it. just in-case there was anyone else looking.

```
(define (word lis)
  (if (null? lis)
      '()
      (append (word (cdr lis))
              (list (car lis)))))
```

Comment: Oh! This is truly horrible. Please don't turn this in.

Comment: @JohnClements What exactly makes it horrible? Using `append` (due to its time complexity)? The recursive application not being in tail position? `car` and `cdr` instead of `first` and `rest`? Something else? (I'm a newbie Racketeer, so I'd like to learn.)

Comment: You're right, I wasn't being helpful at all. This solution takes n^2 time. Doing better requires using an accumulator, which makes it linear. In retrospect, I wish I hadn't said this. :)