# How do you reverse a sequence in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm learning Racket just for fun. 
I've got a question. Is there a way to reverse a [sequence](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html)? A sort of generic function for reversing things like:

```
(sequence-reverse "Hello")
(sequence-reverse '(1 2 3))
```

Comment: https://github.com/DracoAter/Structure-and-Interpretation-of-Computer-Programs-Solutions/blob/master/ex2.39

Comment: Thank you for the input. But I believe the answer that you've provided won't work on strings. I'm looking for a builtin thing which would work on `sequence?` contract providers.

Comment: `(reverse '(a b c))`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384173/how-to-print-a-string-in-backward-in-scheme

Comment: I thought about that too, but `reverse` applies only to lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that some sequences are infinite, for example the one given by `(in-integers)`. For a finite sequence you can use:

```
(define (sequence-reverse s)
  (reverse
    (sequence->list s)))
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that there's a list->sequence function in Racket.

Comment: That's probably why Racket doesn't have reversed `for` forms.

Comment: @wickstopher  You are right! I forgot that "sequence" simply means "list, vector, stream, etc." I changed the definition above to return a list (which is an example of a sequence). If the original poster needs a sequence of the same type as the result, he should use your solution.

Comment: Interestingly, this solution won't work for hashes, though they've a hash->list function.

Comment: I think by `in-integers` you meant `in-naturals`—`in-integers` wouldn't have a starting point. :P

Comment: Reading the docs of `sequence->list` I see it requires the elements of the sequence must be single values. That explains why sequence->list fails on hash tables.

Comment: Many years late: `list->sequence` is spelled `in-list`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in function to do what you want. If you're just concerned with strings and lists, try something like this:

```
(define (sequence-reverse seq)
    (cond ((null? seq) seq)
          ((list? seq) (reverse seq))
          ((string? seq) (list->string (reverse (string->list seq))))
          (error "Bad sequence")))
```

You can add other conditions as you see fit - e.g. Vectors offer similar functionality by way of the functions `list->vector` and `vector->list`. You probably don't want blanket functionality for all sequences, though. It doesn't really make sense to reverse a hash table or a dictionary.

Comment: In Racket it is fine to use list? (it only takes O(1) amortized time due to immutable conses).